# How to Configuring ELMAH logging in sql server in n tier application

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, elmah

I have N trier application as usual Presentation layer with ASP.Net MVC3 + Service Layer in WCF + Data layer Normal class project C# to  host the WCF service at run time we have Hosting Layer. this hosting layer actually have the web.config for service layer. i want to provide loggin in WCF and  Data layer using the ELMAH as per client recommendation.

How can i configure it in this scenario to get service layer exception and Data layer exceptions? If i made changes in web.config of WCF hosting services (Following [this](http://adilmughal.com/blog/2011/05/configuring-elmah-with-wcf-using-nuget/)) then do is that essential to add in each method enclosed with `try{}... catch{}` ? or only web.config settings enough to log the error. In presentation layer I able to send error to database using web.config settings, global.asax setting and  `Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(e);.` in sample method. so is this above code line mandatory to add in each method?

```
Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(e);
```